# How to change default terminal to iTerm2 in Nitrous Desktop

Tags: nitrousio

Regardless of system default terminal in OS X, when clicking on SSH for VM, the standard Terminal is opened. Is it possible to change that to iTerm2? If so, can it open a new tab in last window, rather than opening new window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Nitrous Desktop for Mac](http://www.nitrous.io/mac) does not have an option to open iTerm2 instead of the standard Terminal at this time, so you will need to open iTerm2 through your applications folder.

You may be interested in setting up a keyboard shortcut with iTerm2 in order to quick connect to your Nitrous box. Take a look at the [best practices](http://help.nitrous.io/best-practices/) guide in order to create a profile within iTerm2 for your Nitrous box.

Comment: The link gives 404 as of Nov 2016.